# Check whether a value exists in a table; show MessageBox

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have an 'invoices' table with a column for the invoice number.

When adding a new invoice, I would like to check if it already exists. If it exists, produce a MessageBox to the user that there's already a record with this number.

How can this be done?

I'm using Visual Basic 2010 and SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
Dim SomeInvoiceNumber As String = ""
Using conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("YourConnectionString")
    Using cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 1 FROM Invoices WHERE InvoiceNumber = @InvNum"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvNum", SomeInvoiceNumber)
        conn.Open()
        Dim exists As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()

        If exists = "1" Then
            MessageBox.Show(SomeInvoiceNumber & " exists already.")
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```